# 24V AC-AC Power Supply Outputs ~80V Unloaded

Tags: power-supply, ac

I have a AC-AC power supply with a secondary coil rated as 24V, 1500mA and 36VAC. Primary is 230V, suited for use in the UK.

I measured the output of this power supply with an oscilloscope, and it was showing a sine wave that with peak-to-peak voltage of around 80V.

This seems really high to me, but I have little experience with AC-AC power supplies, and not sure if this is normal. I know, for instance, that an unregulated DC power supply will output higher voltage than stated when unloaded. This might be the case here, but for the output to be so much larger seems unusual.

Is what I am seeing normal behaviour, or is the power supply (which ~5 years old) faulty and should be replaced?

Comment: Did some research, and it seems that the 24V output is the RMS voltage, so peak positive/negative would be around 37V, giving a peak-to-peak of around 74V. Adding a bit of leeway for unregulated output, 80Vpp doesn't seem so outrageous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

80 volts peak-to-peak is...

\${ 80V \over \sqrt 2 \times 2} \approx 28.284V\$

... 28.3 volts RMS. This is an error of...

\$1 - {24V \over 28.284V} \approx 0.1515\$

... 15.15%. That is a bit high, but may be in spec for the equipment it's meant for, since the voltage will drop a bit when the supply is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my calculations! This PSU drives a AC solenoid, which will one, load it quite a bit, and two, shouldn't be too sensitive to a few % here or there.